# Visualize how the 5d Dold manifold and Wu manifold are cobordant via a 6d manifolds with boundaries

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, characteristic-classes, cobordism, surgery-theory

1. Are there simple intuitions and arguments to visualize why the following two 5-manifolds are cobordant to each other with the oriented structures? (They can be two boundaries of 6-dimensional oriented [stable special orthogonal $SO$] manifold)?

- [Dold manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dold_manifold) $(\mathbf{CP}^2 \times S^1)/\mathbf{Z}_2$, where we identify the $(z,x) \in (\mathbf{CP}^2 \times S^1)/\mathbf{Z}_2$
  with $(\bar{z},-x) \in (\mathbf{CP}^2 \times S^1)/\mathbf{Z}_2$.
- Wu manifold: $SU(3)/SO(3)$.

2. What are examples of the 6-dimensional oriented manifold, which have Dold manifold and Wu manifold as two boundaries?

p.s. Of course, there is a sophisticated way of checking the $\Omega_5^{SO}=\mathbf{Z}_2$ has only a cobordism invariant $w_2(M)w_3(M)$. It can be shown that both Dold manifold and Wu manifold take nontrivial values under $w_2(M)w_3(M)$. But this is not intuitive enough for me to fully understand the manifold structure. Any simple reasonings, derivations, intuitions and arguments are welcome!

Comment: A cobordism is constructed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/270869/21564).

Comment: this is helpful, I will have a look +1